# Atribuição de valor em array de struct em c

Tags: c

Estou com duvida sobre como conseguir atribuir valores para um **array** de uma **struct**, onde não consigo acessar na memória virtual para efetuar essa atribuição de valor.
Pode ser que seja uma coisa simples, já peço desculpa pela minha ignorância :)

**Struct Phone**

```
typedef struct phone {
    char prefix[2];
    char number[9];
    char type[16];
} Phone;
```

**Struct Person**

```
#include "Phone.h"

typedef struct person {
    char name[32];
    Phone phones[3];
} Person;
```

Quando tento atribuir algum valor para a função ***input*** esse valor não é passado para a struct ***Person*** que esta local em outra função, ***menu***. Isso tudo se tratando do array de ***Phones*** que existe dentro da struct ***Person***.

***Funções***

```
void input(Phone* phone) {
    printf("Insira o prefixo do telefone: ");
    setbuf(stdin, NULL); // limpa buffer do teclado
    scanf("%s", phone->prefix);

    printf("Insira o número do telefone: ");
    setbuf(stdin, NULL);
    scanf("%s", phone->number);

    printf("Insira o tipo de telefone: ");
    setbuf(stdin, NULL);
    scanf("%s", phone->type);
}

void inputMult(Phone* phones[3]) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        input(&phones[i]);
    }
}

void menu() {
    Person person;
    inputMult(&person.phones);
}
```

***OBS***
Usei vários `setbuf(stdin, NULL);`, porque estava tendo vários problemas em outras partes do código, que pegavam outras informações além das digitadas nos campos.

Answer (score 2):

Seguinte, mexer com ponteiros é bem complicado, ainda mais se estiver no começo(eu mesmo não entendo por completo). No teu código tem muita passagem de função que não é do mesmo tipo, e acredito que seja esse o motivo de estar dando erro. Pelo que eu entendi, na void menu() você passa o endereço de memória de um parâmetro (inputMult(&person.phones)), mas a função inputMult está programada para receber um ponteiro. Então acredito que esse seja o problema. Fiz a implementação utilizando alocação dinâmica, veja se lhe serve de algo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct phone {
    char prefix[2];
    char number[9];
    char type[16];
} Phone;

typedef struct person {
    char name[32];
    Phone phones[3];
} Person;
Person *criaperson(){
    Person *p = (Person*)malloc(sizeof(Person));
}


void input(Person *phone) {
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<3; i++){
        printf("Insira o prefixo do telefone: ");
    setbuf(stdin, NULL); // limpa buffer do teclado
    scanf("%s]",phone->phones[i].prefix);

    printf("Insira o número do telefone: ");
    setbuf(stdin, NULL);
    scanf("%s]", phone->phones[i].number);

    printf("Insira o tipo de telefone: ");
    setbuf(stdin, NULL);
    scanf("%s]", phone->phones[i].type);
    }
}

int main() {
    Person *novo = criaperson();
    input(novo);
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<3; i++){
        printf("%s %s %s\n", novo->phones[i].prefix, novo->phones[i].number, novo->phones[i].type);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oi Bruno, muito obrigado. Me confundi muito por ter criado várias funções, esse coisa de ponteiros é realmente complicada, eu sempre me perco entre passagem de endereços de ponteiros.

Comment: Por nada! É assim mesmo, ponteiros é bem chatinho. Mas com certeza você vai acostumar. O importante é não parar de codar haha